# Center childs in linear layout in android

Tags: android-linearlayout

I try to do the following: I have a linear layout. So I want to split it in 3 parts (equal parts) for 3 children. So I make weightSum = 3 and every child weight to 1. But there is one more problem - every child is not centralized in its own part ! I try to set layout gravity to the childs, but there is no effect. Is there any solution for this. Warning: I don't want to set gravity=center of the linear layout (this centralized the children, which I don't want and moreover if I remove one of them the effect is not I want). 
Thanks in advance.
Also why when I add views in linear layout and set gravity of the layout to center then there is space between the views ? How can I control this or remove it?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap every child of linear layout into a relative layout and then give layout:centerHorizontal = true to each relative layout.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is overhead in my opinion. I didn't want to do that, because I have to have a lot of layouts. Is there any better solution.